# APC SmartUPS - possible to control outlet group from command line?

Tags: command-line, debian, automation, ups

My home (Debian) server has an APC SmartUPS 1500 LCD (model SMT1500I) attached via USB. Monitoring and automatic shutdown works perfectly through apcupsd. Since I have a lot of spare headroom on the UPS, I make use of one of the nifty features - Outlet Groups - to attach my desktop PC and all its accessories. I have the front panel key combination to switch the outlets on and off memorised. What I would like to know is if there is a way to do this from the command line - I have reshuffled my home and would like to power my home cinema system in the same way, but able to switch it on and off remotely from my laptop rather than walking across the room.

I can find very little information on this through Google, although there is some reference to using the optional network management card - this is still expensive for few extra features and I'd rather not buy it if there's another way. I'd prefer to keep within apcupsd, but if there's other software that can do this, I will consider switching.

Comment: It's possible to do via the web interface provided by the native PowerChute software (without a network management card) so I'd consider that a vote in your favor. The question of course then is *how*...